# Proper Term For This Code

Tags: css

i need to know what the proper term for this code is. someone sent this to me and it was what ii was looking for, but i need the proper term so i can learn it myself. what i'm looking for is the multiple colors on a webpage.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>I am Awesome!</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, #nav, #header, .white-box, .blue-box {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
height: 100%;
}
h1{
margin: 0;
padding: 150px 0;
}
#nav
{
height: 60px;
color: #fff;
position: fixed;
background: darkblue;
}
#header {
background: red;
text-align: center;
}
#header, .white-box, .blue-box {
height: 400px;
}
.white-box {
background: #ccc;
}
.blue-box {
background: lightblue;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='nav'>Navigation</div>
    <div id='header'>
        <h1>Some Cool Image!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='white-box'>Content!</div>
    <div class='blue-box'>More Content!</div>
    <div class='white-box'>And Something Else!</div>
    <div class='blue-box'>Redundancy!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I answered your question for you, it explains what the code is.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sadly your question is confusing. You ask what the *proper term* is for the code above, then go on to ask about multiple colors? Could you please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is no proper term for having multi-colors on a web page. You have a simple css code defining various classes with various colors for different parts of your site. So be easy, Not every thing needs to have a name. If its still confusing, let me know in commnents

Comment: It will be also nice to have a jsfiddle of it so that one can see practically what you are talking

Comment: could you possibly send me a link to where I can learn in myself. I just started coding recently so I'm new to this. so far i know HTML and basic CSS

Comment: You can use w3schools for basic though it has some errors nut still its a useful resource. css-tricks.com can also help you a lot in regards of some advance css codes and effects. Trial and error is the best learning. search Google for your codes and  discover more tags daily from w3schools. For advance learning  w2c.org is also the  best

Comment: whats the advanced learning website. the one you gave me is incorrect. and i have been using w3schools its decent but its not the best website.

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/
http://html.net/tutorials/css/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css (for advance learnings)

Comment: okay thank you, this really helped. do you have any other websites that you recommend when leaning javascript?

Answer (score -1):

The proper term for this is Cascading Style Sheets, also known as CSS. CSS is used to style an HTML document and make it look fancier and do formatting changes that HTML cannot do (i.e change the color of the text or change the font size)

CSS can be edited in programs such as [JSfiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

To insert CSS into an HTML document, the  tag can be used or you can reference the CSS stylesheet using href.

CSS can be applied to 3 different things:

By element type (i.e. p{}

By ID: `#main{}` OR

By class: `.button{}`

The CSS code is put inbetween the curly braces.

For example, to change the color of element p to blue I would use

```
p {
color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's Cascading Style Sheets, otherwise known as CSS. There are a few different ways to apply the styles:

By element type: `body { ... }`

By ID: `#nav { ... }`

By class: `.white-box { ... }`

You can read more about it online; one example is here: http://w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: He has tagged `css` :)

Comment: The question was 'i need to know what the proper term for this code is'- what that's using is different CSS selectors, which is what I described and linked to.